# Are there reasons you shouldn't do plyometrics workouts barefoot?

Tags: shoes, plyometrics, clothing

As a follow up to this [question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/4825/98) and [answer](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/4841/98), are there any reasons why I shouldn't perform a plyometrics workout barefoot? I've tried both, and I definitely feel more stress on my feet when barefoot, but I'm able to catch the floor better on jumps, and I imagine that over time my feet will adapt. Is the extra stress to the joints (assuming there is any) significant?

Answer (score 2):

I had to check exactly what "plyometrics workout" means - I assume you mean things like [box jumps](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UweKybOuivA), [precision jumps](http://parkourpedia.com/technique/precision-jump), [jumping lunges](http://www.builtlean.com/2011/09/29/jump-lunges-plyometric-leg-exercise/), etc. I have done these both with and without shoes, but the past few years I prefer without.

As you've mentioned in the question, there are reasons against doing this. You will feel more impact on your feet, and less cushioning than you would if using a typical athletic shoe. However for me, this stress (on the bones, joints, ligaments, etc.) is the main reason for going barefoot. With the proper progression, jumping this way forces you to use learn how to use your muscles to absorb shock, and you will develop a "cat-like" agility. I try to always land gently and quietly. If I can land safely and gently even on a hard concrete or pavement surface, I believe that is a higher level of fitness, and in my view this type of training is more likely to prevent injury than cause it.